# Id cannot be found (Resource Issue)

Tags: android, resources

Okay so I'm working on a project and I'm trying to use buttons with text inside of them in an activity, but eclipse can't find the id or chooser.xml

Here's myActivity class

```
package com.xxxxxxx;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.ImageButton;  
import android.view.*;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {`

    private Button mButton1;
    private Button mButton2;
    private Button mButton3;
    private Button mButton4;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //chooser is underlined (chooser cannot be resolved or is not a field)
        setContentView(R.layout.chooser);
                //all ids are underlined(id cannot be resolved or is not a field)
        mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

         mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }
         });
         mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activty3.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }
         });

         mButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activity4.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }
         });
         mButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Activity5.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }
         });
             }

    }
```

Here's the chooser.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_1"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:text="@string/button_1" /> 

   <Button 
   android:text="@string/button_2"   
   android:id="@+id/button_2"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

   <Button 
   android:id="@+id/button_3"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:text="@string/button_3"   
  />

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_4"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:text="@string/button_4"  
     />  

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the string resource xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources> 
    <string name="app_name">Test App</string>  
    <string name="test_image">test.png</string>   
    <string name="button_1">button_1</string>  
    <string name="button_2">button_2</string>  
    <string name="button_3">button_3</string>  
    <string name="button_4">button_4</string>  
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your gen files most likely aren't generated yet. Try building it, it should make the lines go away.

Comment: plus one, this was the fix for this error in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to import your R class. `import <android package>.R` Ref: [R.id cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483732/r-id-cannot-be-resolved) AND [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

2) Aren't your `R.id.button1` supposed to be `R.id.button_1` and so forth for other buttons?

Comment: I went back and imported the .R Package and it helped clean up some. I also fixed the button1 to button_1's but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Is chooser.xml in the correct folder (the default layout folder provided with the project)? Have you perhaps tried to go to Project and choose Clean? Everything looks okay in your code.

Comment: Clean helped clean a lot out.

Although it still cannot find chooser.xml

it's in 
-res
-layouts
-chooser.xml

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, though I still stumbled upon it in my search for a similar problem.  When I built the android project, it automatically added:

```
import android.R;
```

When I used the advice above,

```
import <android package>.R;
```

and I still used R.id....., it still propagated an error.  I removed

```
import android.R;
```

and no errors.